# Arbitrary lens design using POV-ray

Tags: graphics, raytracing, povray

I am presently trying to use Povray for generating some caustic patterns. I have to design a lens of an arbitrary shape. The lens can be thought of as a sheet of glass. The incident surface of the lens is a plane, and the refractive surface is of varying height. I have saved this varying Z coordinate as a height map. I was wondering what is the best way of creating this object, and specifying the parameters of the lens, such as refractive index. I want to place a screen behind the lens, where the desired caustic pattern can be observed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

POV Ray has a [heightfield](http://www.povray.org/documentation/view/3.6.0/279/) object for this very purpose.

You should be able to use your heightmap in it (assuming it's a grayscale bitmap) and assign whatever refractive index you desire.

Comment: I saw the heightfield object, but it started to give me errors whenever I tried to assign a refractive index to it. Ideally I would like to create a box like object, and then make the surface vary according to the heightfield for one side of the box.  I couldn't find any way of changing the box object.

Answer (score 0):

Make an intersection of a cube and the hightfield